# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm trying to create a simple registration Servlet using DAO pattern, the exception comes, when I try to add data into database. Seems like ID doesnt get value for some reason but why?

```
integrity constraint violation: 
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException NOT NULL check constraint; 
SYS_CT_10092 table: CUSTOMER column: ID
```

Database schema (using hsqldb):

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 AS INTEGER START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE customer (
     id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     surname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR seq1,'Jane','Doe','123'); --test data
```

Dao method for inserting data into database :

```
public void addCustomer(Customers c) {
    try {
        pst = getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into customer(first_name,surname,code)"
                + " values(?,?,?)");

        pst.setString(1, c.getFirst_name());
        pst.setString(2, c.getSurname());
        pst.setString(3, c.getCode());
        pst.executeUpdate();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        closeResources();
    }
}
```

Calling dao method in servlet class :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String code = request.getParameter("code");

    Customers customer = new Customers();
    customer.setFirst_name(firstname);
    customer.setSurname(lastName);
    customer.setCode(code);
    dao.addCustomer(customer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to create the id column as an IDENTITY column and insert null in your prepared statement:

> Identity Auto-Increment Columns
>
> Each table can contain one auto-increment column, known as the
>   IDENTITY column. An IDENTITY column is always treated as the primary
>   key for the table (as a result, multi-column primary keys are not
>   possible with an IDENTITY column present). Support has been added for
>   CREATE TABLE ( IDENTITY, ...) as a shortcut.
>
> Since 1.7.2, the SQL standard syntax is used by default, which allows
>   the initial value to be specified. The supported form is(
>   INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH n, [INCREMENT BY
>   m])PRIMARY KEY, ...). Support has also been added for BIGINT identity
>   columns. As a result, an IDENTITY column is simply an INTEGER or
>   BIGINT column with its default value generated by a sequence
>   generator.
>
> When you add a new row to such a table using an INSERT INTO
>    ...; statement, you can use the NULL value for the
>   IDENTITY column, which results in an auto-generated value for the
>   column. The IDENTITY() function returns the last value inserted into
>   any IDENTITY column by this connection. Use CALL IDENTITY(); as an SQL
>   statement to retrieve this value. If you want to use the value for a
>   field in a child table, you can use INSERT INTO  VALUES
>   (...,IDENTITY(),...);. Both types of call to IDENTITY() must be made
>   before any additional update or insert statements are issued on the
>   database.
>
> The next IDENTITY value to be used can be set with the
>
> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN  RESTART WITH ;

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch02.html#N104B3

Answer (score 0):

According to CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 AS INTEGER START WITH 1;

pst = getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into customer(first_name,surname,code)"
    + " values(?,?,?)");

Has to be :

pst = getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into customer(first_name,surname,code)"
    + " values(NEXT VALUE FOR seq1,?,?,?)");